# Do skill DCs have to be multiples of 5?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, difficulty-class

In D&D 5e, spell save DCs can be any number based on the calculation ([Player's Basic Rules pp. 22, 30](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/PlayerDnDBasicRules_v0.2.pdf)):

> Spell save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Wisdom modifier
>   Spell save DC = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Intelligence modifier

However, the DM screen has a table for setting skill DCs for tasks, which are all divisible by 5 (I don't have my screen to reference the exact figures).

Are there any reasons not to set task DCs to anything between these defined, round numbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### A DC could be any (real) number you like.

The reference table shows descriptors for DCs of 10, 15, 20, &c. This is just to provide you some touchstones--you can set intermediate DCs any time you'd like.

(However, the fine-tuning by 5% probabilities that provides isn't, in my experience, *that* useful and increases my cognitive load more than necessary. I've generally been happy with just using the "major" DCs.)

#### P.S.

If you've considering setting a DC much lower than ten or upwards of thirty, please read [5 Simple Rules for Dating My Teenaged Skill System](http://theangrygm.com/five-simple-rules-for-dating-my-teenaged-skill-system/) by AngryGM. It's an excellent expansion on the DMG's section "Using Ability Scores" (p.237) which says, in part:

> Only call for a roll if there is a meaningful consequence for failure.
>
> When deciding whether to use a roll, ask yourself two questions:
>
> - Is a task so easy...?
> - Is a task so inappropriate or impossible...?

(Warning: Angry's excellent advice and analyses are salted liberally with rude and vulgar language.)

Comment: Technically this answer is correct, but as long as we're giving advice, I strongly urge you to stick with positive integers. ;)

Comment: Darn. I was hoping to use an [imaginary number](https://www.google.com/search?q=+imaginary+number)

Comment: As long as you're willing to compute modulus in your head, I suppose you could always go with "roll >= |DC|." That's a little nerdy for me, though =\

Comment: Negative DCs could matter if you've got low enough ability scores,  no proficiency added in, and bad enough luck...

Answer (score 6):

DCs are whole numbers, the whole game plays in whole numbers - hence the round up or round down when dividing a number.
The example numbers in the DMG (p. 238) are guidelines of how difficult a skill/save is.

- 5 - Very Easy
- 10 - Easy
- 15 - Moderate
- 20 - Hard
- 25 - Very Hard
- 30 - Nearly Impossible

It's up to the GM (even with a module, the GM can adjust) what the difficulty will be; it can be any number.  Typically an NPC will have its own attributes to have their Spell DC, resistance to intimidation/persuasion, perception, stealth, etc.  The DC would be calculated by their ability modifier, proficiency bonus, and possibly a base #, which will commonly not be in the set divisible by 5 (but it can happen).

Example: (Basic Rules, DM, p. 29)

> Giant Wolf Spider
>   STR DEX CON INT WIS CHA
>   12 (+1) 16 (+3) 13 (+1) 3 (−4) 12 (+1) 4 (−3)
>   Skills Perception +3, Stealth +7
>   Senses blindsight 10 ft., darkvision 60 ft.
>   *passive Perception 13*

Comment: This is probably the correct answer to the literal question they are asking  (can a DC be any number? No - it has to be a whole number). However, this answer would be improved  by breaking it into smaller sections to improve readability.

Comment: Edited for format.  Please review the edit to make sure your intended meaning was preserved.

Comment: @indigochild Actually, no reason it has to be a whole number. It has to be a *real* number for the question "roll + mods >= DC?" to make any sense, but there's nothing that a DC of 14.3 or 5\pi breaks. (It doesn't gain you anything, but it works....)

Comment: @nitsua60 - You could set a DC to be any real number you wanted, but only whole DCs make sense.  If a DC is a number you need to roll, and your die can only roll whole numbers, the DC must also be a whole number. It's not that you couldn't create a DC of 13.5, it's that it wouldn't mean anything because you couldn't roll a 13.5.

Comment: @indigochild DC's not a number that you need to roll, it's one you need to meet-or-exceed. But I absolutely agree that making a DC 13.5 rather than 14 adds no actionable information to the game; that's why I say "it doesn't gain you anything."

Comment: 30 is actually impossible to most people. 25 is near impossible to most people (they require a +3 bonus in the necessary ability score).

Comment: @ShadowKras by level 5 (not very far) it's pretty common for a Bard or Rogue to have a +10 in their favorite skill. An ability at 18 (15 starting array, +1 racial, +2 from L4 ASI) gives +4; proficiency at L5 is +3, doubled by Expertise is +6 for a total of +10. At 9th level you could be talking +13. Any any character only needs a 1-level dip in Rogue to be in the same situation, just one level later.

Comment: Yeah, but bards and rogues are heroes, adventurers, uncommon people. NPC's in general don't have stats that high or multiple proficiency bonuses.

Comment: Okay, @ShadowKras, I guess I don't understand your point, then. James quotes correctly from the DMG, and I've pointed out why I, for one, think the descriptors are accurate. If you have a problem with the descriptors I suggest you contact Jeremy Crawford or Mike Mearls with your suggestion. (Also, your embedded assumptions about NPC abilities/skills/experience are a setting decision you've made, nothing canonical.)

Comment: My point is that your "average joe" will never have bonuses so high, heroes and exceptional people will. The DMG actually is very cryptic about how to build npcs, and their stats will vary vastly from table to table: http://bit.ly/2bG9X2J

Answer (score 4):

**No**

This serves as a general rule of thumb, to give you an idea of what constitutes an easy or difficult check, based on the overall balancing of the game.  However, the DM can increase or decrease a check by any arbitrary amount.

For example, in the video series *Critical Role* the DM (Matt Mercer) often changes the DC of a given check based on the actions of players.  For instance, a player delivering a genuinely convincing speech might have an easier time on a Deception check than one who mumbled something ill-conceived.